# How do you manipulate inequality in quadratics or manipulating inequality signs in general (Grade 10)??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I have been assigned to do a quadratic word problem. One of them included solving the quadratic inequation of $-5t^2 + 20t > 15$. I am not sure how to start off and I have no memory of doing inequalities. Thank you for trying!!

Comment: Have your teacher taught you anything about this, and if so what don't you understand? /// You should format formulas with Latex, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference .

Comment: Factoring is always a good idea.  Do that first.  Then note that the product of two numbers is positive iff they are both negative or both positive.

Comment: @user202729 I can not recall if my teacher has taught me about inequalities but i know quadratics and parabolas stuff like that. I am doing some unfamiliar questions that my teacher has not been teaching in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your inequality after dividing by $-5$ and we get $$t^2-4t+3<0$$
This is equivalent to $$(t-3)(t-1)<0$$
Can you solve this?
Write $$-5t^2+20t-15>0$$ then we divide by $-5$ we get

$$t^2-4t+3<0$$ solving the equation

$$t^2-4t+3=0$$ we get $$t_1=3,t_2=1$$

Comment: I think you wanted to divide by -5

Comment: Yes the $5$ lies in the neiberhood of the $4$ on the keybord! (joke)

Comment: Sorry, @Dr.SonnhardGraubner may I ask you how come you turned > into < from the initial question?

Comment: It is clear now?

Comment: You can me ask everything, but i will know not all!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes, but why did you changed the sign? and how? Are there rules that i might not know?

Comment: It is a law, if you divide in a inequality by a negative number, you must change the sign.

Comment: For example $$5>0$$ then dividing by $-1$ we get $$-5<0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  so if i divide in a inequality by a positive  number, do i still change the sign? and thank you for help!

Comment: No, in this case the sign doesn't change.

Comment: Thanks! alot i have got 1 more question on interval notation 0< x >12 how would you write that in interval notation?

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(t)=5t^2-20t+15$. You know about parabolas, hence you know that $f$ takes negative values exactly between its zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

Solving an inequality is much like solving an equality - but you must remember to change the sign if you multiply or divide by a negative number. In general, the operations used to solve equalities and inequalities (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, squaring both sides, etc.) can be viewed as applying a function to both sides. If the inequality holds, and the function that you are applying is increasing, then it still holds after applying the function. If the function is decreasing, then the opposite inequality is now true (change the sign). If the function is neither increasing or decreasing, then it gets more complicated and you must evaluate cases (think squaring $x < y$ when $x$ is large negative and $y$ is small positive).

Comment: ok so if i have something like y= -x^2 + 5x, i would now divide -1 by both sides and now i have to change the sign right? but to which signs? < or this >

Comment: $y= -x^2 + 5x$ is not an inequality...

Comment: yes but im asked to turn it into an inequality!